# open a specific tab in modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How do I open a specific tab inside a modal using Javascript? Here is my code. When someone clicks on the following buttons, E.g OPEN TAB1 should open TAB1 content and OPEN TAB2 should open TAB2 content

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="#loginModal">OPEN TAB1</a>

<a class="btn" id="btnRegister">OPEN TAB2</a>

<!-- modal -->

<div class="well modal fade" id="loginModal">
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="span10 offset1">
                      <div id="modalTab">
                          <div class="tab-content">
                              <div class="tab-pane active" id="login">
                                 TAB 1 CONTENTS
                              </div>
                              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                             TAB 2 CONTENTS 
                            <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">OPEN TAB 1
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer well">

            <a href="#create"  data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-success">OPEN TAB 2</a>
          </div>
              </div>
```

the following script doesnot work for me

```
 <script> 
    $('#btnRegister').on('click', function() {

         $('#loginModal').modal('show');
        $('.modalTab #create').tab('show');

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/te6zdd3d/, did you import jquery and bootstrap?

Comment: Yes the code works.. but , the javascript doesnot work.. i mean it just opens the modal dialog but I want to open "TAB2" on click.. the second line is not working

Comment: what is openregister()?, .modalTab is not a class in your html?

Comment: thats just a function, actually it does nothing.. you can ignore it.. so when I click on the btnRegister, it should make the  tab with id="create" active <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                             TAB 2 CONTENTS

Comment: I am stuck with it from an hour.. :( only thing is that i need to open the TAB2 content on click of the btnRegister

Comment: first should it not be #modalTab in the selector?

Comment: you mean    $('#modalTab #create').tab('show'); ? it didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: data-toggle tab and href on OpenTAB2 link.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmmLv0ey/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="#loginModal">OPEN TAB1</a>

<a class="btn" data-toggle="tab" id="btnRegister" href="#create2">OPEN TAB2</a>

<!-- modal -->

<div class="well modal fade" id="loginModal">
      <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
          <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span10 offset1">
                  <div id="modalTab">
                      <div class="tab-content">
                          <div class="tab-pane" id="login">
                             TAB 1 CONTENTS
                          </div>
                          <div class="tab-pane"  id="create2">
                         TAB 2 CONTENTS 
                        <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">OPEN TAB 1
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer well">

        <a href="#create"  data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-success">OPEN TAB 2</a>
      </div>
          </div>
                   <script> 
$('#btnRegister').on('click', function() {

                       $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    $('#create2').tab('show');
    openRegister();

});
</script>
```